# How To get mp3 file list from SdCard with ContentResolver.Query on Android?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-cursor

I created a folder that's Cuzler in mnt/sdcard and put some mp3 files..  and here codes what I am using..

```
File cuzFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Cuzler/");
String storageFolder = cuzFolder.getPath(); 

Uri urlCuz = Uri.parse(storageFolder); 
Log.i(TAG, "CUZ: " + urlCuz.toString());
Cursor cur = mContentResolver.query(urlCuz, null,

MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " = 1", null, null);
Log.i(TAG, "Query finished. " + (cur == null ? "Returned NULL." : "Returned a cursor."));
```

cur returns null.. I've given the write/read permissions.  I am making a mp3 player that will play some mp3s in a folder in sdcard, the path is true because I am downloading mp3s to this folder and no problem. But I do not understand why query returns null ?

I also tried something like

```
Uri urlCuz = Uri.parse("content://" + storageFolder);
```

and gave direct link like mnt/sdcard/Cuzler or /mnt/scard/Cuzler

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        ContentResolver resolver = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver();
        ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();


        String GENRE_ID      = MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID;
        String GENRE_NAME    = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME;
        String SONG_ID       = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
        String SONG_TITLE    = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
        String SONG_ARTIST   = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST;
        String SONG_ALBUM    = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
        String SONG_YEAR     = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR;
        String SONG_TRACK_NO = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
        String SONG_FILEPATH = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
        String SONG_DURATION = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION;


        String[] genreColumns = {
               SONG_ID,
                SONG_TITLE
        };

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
            }

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
            // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

            return;
        }

        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,genreColumns,null,null,null);
        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
//            genreIdToGenreNameMap.put(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1));
             stringArrayList.add(cursor.getString(1));

        cursor.close();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stringArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: in manifest file you have to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Instead of dumping a big code block, it would be nice to add some comments & explanation to your post for future readers.